# Action Sheet picker on Button IOS

Tags: ios, actionsheetpicker

HeyI want to do that This my button and in button there is textfield I want to do that when I pressed on button the action sheet picker become appear and give 4 to 5 list of string whatever I select it will apear on textfield which is in button. please help me

[image]

Comment: when click on action sheet button set the textfield.text=@"button title"

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding a target for your button. In Objective-C, that would be like this:

```
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then create the method `buttonPressed`. An example of that would be:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.myButton]) {
        //This is where you can create the UIAlertController
    }
}
```

Then, to create the `UIAlertController`:

```
UIAlertController *myAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                     message:@"Message"
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
```

Then you create actions for what each button you want to have appear on the action sheet. You need to have a title for the button and an action for them, though the action block can be empty.

```
UIAlertAction *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action 1"
                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                    //Whatever you want to have happen when the button is pressed
                                                }];
[myAlertController addAction:action1];

//repeat for all subsequent actions...

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                         // It's good practice to give the user an option to do nothing, but not necessary
                                                     }];
[myAlertController addAction:cancelAction];
```

Lastly, you present the `UIAlertController`:

```
[self presentViewController:myAlertController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{

                 }];
```

NOTE:

If you're building for iPad and using an Action Sheet style for the UIAlertController, then you will need to set a source for the UIAlertController to present from. This can be done like this:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
    if ([myAlertController.popoverPresentationController respondsToSelector:@selector(setSourceView:)]) { // Check for availability of this method
        myAlertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.myButton;
    } else {
        myAlertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.myButton.frame;

    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that if this is to be run on an iPad, a `popoverPresentation` must be declared. Usually a bar button item, or define a `sourceRect` and a `sourceView`. It will crash on iPad otherwise

Comment: That is an excellent point. I will add that note to my answer.